# Dual boot Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, 14.04

I'm new at Linux, and I decided to try Ubuntu. I had a Ubuntu 12 dual boot installed using the Windows installer and it seemed to work fine. Now I cannot find the same program online. I now try to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with a USB and the message I get is:

```
This computer currently has multiple operating systems on it. What would you like to do?
```

Then I have an option of erasing my hard drive or manually partitioning it (which I do not know how to do).

This is the code I get when I go to the partition page:

```
dev/sda1  FAT32  8066 MB Windows NT/2000/XP
dev/sda2  NTFS  191979MB Windows XP Home Edition
```

Why don't I get the message for a dual boot like I used to?

Comment: You'll have to do the manually partitioning, if only to point to where are the disk the new operating system will go. You have two Windows systems installed each with its own partition and you'll need another for Ubuntu. (You may also be able to add a new drive and put Ubuntu on it).

Answer (score 0):

You want to manually partition your drive. This just means that you will split (i.e., partition) your harddrive into two sections, one for Windows, and one for Ubuntu. Then, when your computer starts, you will have the option to select which partition to boot to. (This is exactly the concept behind dual-booting.)

Answer (score 0):

The **windows xp support is ending now** . I unfortunately feel that I have to use windows too sometimes . I run **virtualbox with windows xp** . I use 10GB of my disk which is partitions of linux , everything around it is xt4 . I believe you minimize vulnerabilities and you don’t have to sacrifice much . I recommend it , if of course your computer can take it. You can set the virtual machine as you wish ( set 2 cores and at 512 M ram , its a good start ) . You can find awesome tutorials about that matter . Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

There is good documentation for that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

You can choose
1. "Automatic partition resizing"
2. "Install them side by side, choosing between them each startup"
3. Specify the size of the new partition by dragging the slider at the bottom of the window
4. Click on "Forward".